# Rendering React component with JSON from API not working with .map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the `team` field of the array that I am getting from the API. `console.log(data)` successfully logs it, but when I try to render it, it simply does not show anything. Thank you for the help!

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('url');
            const data = await res.json();
            setData(data);
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            Home
            {data.map((item, i) => {
                    <h1 key={i}>{item.team}</h1>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Data structure of array
`0: {Team: 'Cannons', Win: '4', Loss: '2'} 1: {Team: 'Racers', Win: '6', Loss: '0'}`

Comment: You need to return the <h1> component or wrap it in parentheses if you don't want to use the return keyword.

Comment: @Min {data.map((item, i) => {
                    return <h1 key={i}>{item.team}</h1>
            })}

like this?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise nothing will be rendered

Comment: @Min I've tried with both return and wrapping it in parenthesis and neither of them are working :(

Comment: Would you be able to post the data structure logged in console

Comment: @Min just added it to the original post :)

Answer (score 4):

Your data.map is going to throw an error because when the component renders, it's trying to map a null/undefined value. Set the initial state of data to an empty array or do a check that data is not null before mapping over it. You also need to return the elements from the map

```
const Home = () => {
    // set initial state to an empty array
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('url');
            const data = await res.json();
            setData(data);
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            Home
            {data.map((item, i) => {
              // Added return
                  return  <h1 key={i}>{item.team}</h1>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: An example can be seen here with trying to map a null or undefined array : https://jsfiddle.net/RyanZee/utezxkcj/

Comment: Just tried this, still not working :(

Comment: I see your issue. <h1 key={i}>{item.team}</h1>. If you look at your data structure you posted, team is spelled with a capital T. So it should be <h1 key={i}>{item.Team}</h1> . Here is a code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-https-iyogzh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Even it's mapping a null/undefine value in the first round rendering, could it see the value in the next round of rendering, instead of giving him a empty page all the way ? @RyanZeelie

Comment: @AeLeung So first it will show a blank page and throw an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` because it's trying to map undefined. It will not update the state after that because the app has crashed.  With the state set to an empty array. Nothing would be mapped or returned since there is no key `team`. Only `Team`. As you can see in the codesandbox, it works. So the error must be somewhere else in the code

Comment: just for other purpose, If other programs crashed in this way, mostly we can still see other components rendered on the page, even with error shown on console page. In this case, mostly the page still works. In such a scenario, any problems implied except the fact that the useEffect part would be skipped . @RyanZeelie

Comment: @AeLeung https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#:~:text=As%20of%20React%2016%2C%20errors,the%20whole%20React%20component%20tree. Everything gets unmounted

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your response is an array, try doing

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

If thats not the case point to correct array attribute. Like

```
data.array.map....
```